# Does google use browser fingerprinting?

Tags: web-browser, fingerprinting

I'm wondering whether besides collecting the typical tracking information (IP + cookies) google has already implemented browser fingerprinting? I read sometime not long ago about it being a hypothetical future method for tracking and identifying google users and would like to know if it's already in use officially?

Answer (score 2):

As for what Google does *officially*, it is easily checked: go read Google's [privacy policy](https://www.google.com/intl/en/policies/privacy/) which is prominently advertised. By definition, it will tell you what information Google "officially" gathers.

The implementation of browser fingerprinting is [known and trivial](https://panopticlick.eff.org/). Most of it is just reading the headers from the HTTP request. Whether Google implemented it or not is irrelevant, since they could implement something to the same effect in a matter of a few days at most. What matters is whether they *deployed* such a system -- and, "officially", they did not.

Comment: *Your browser fingerprint appears to be unique among the 3,475,427 tested so far.* oh dear.

Comment: Note that this reply is from 2013. Browser fingerprinting is now quite common practice and not so trivial.